# Solutions to $k$ when $2^k n^2 + 2^k n + 1$ is never a perfect square.

Tags: square-numbers

I need to find possible values of $k$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the equation $2^k n^2 + 2^k n + 1$ will never be a perfect square.

So, I thought, maybe for even $k$ I get solutions because then it is possible to complete the square, like:

Let be $k = 2m; \quad m \in \mathbb{N}$

\begin{align}
2^{2m} n^2 + 2^{2m} n + 1 &= (2^m)^2 n^2 + 2 \cdot 2^{m} \cdot 2^{m-1} n + 1 \\
&= \left(2^m n + 1\right)^2 + 2^{m+1} \left(2^{m-1} - 1 \right) n \\
&= \left(2^m n + 1\right)^2 + \left(2^{m}\right)^2 n - \left(2^m\right) n
\end{align}

But then I am stuck and don't know if it leads me to something.

**Edit 1:**

The comment of Shamim leads me to the condition that if it is a perfect square, it needs to be an odd one because:

\begin{align}
2^k n^2 + 2^k n + 1 \equiv 1 \mod{4}
\end{align}

But still, it does not restrict $k$.

Comment: Quadratic residues modulo $4,3$ may help

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Let note $N=2^kn^2+2^kn+1$.We assume that $0\notin\mathbb N$ because if not then the set solution is obviously empty because $1$ is a square. (Many times you have to consider $0$ as a natural, particularly for Fermat's theorem on the sum of two squares).

►$k=1$ discarded because  $n=3\Rightarrow N=5^2$.

►$k=2$ discarded because of all $n$.

►$k=3$ discarded because  $n=14\Rightarrow N=41^2$

►$k=5$ discarded because $n=5\Rightarrow N=31^2$

We have $$N=\begin{cases}3\cdot(2^{k-1}n)^2+(2^{k-1}n+1)^2 \text{ when $k\gt2$ is even }\\       6\cdot(2^{k-1}n)^2+2(2^{k-1}n+1)^2-1 \text{ when $k\gt5$ is odd }\end{cases} \hspace {15mm}(1)$$
Consider the more general equations involving the equations $(1)$ $$\begin{cases}3x^2+(x+1)^2=z^2\hspace {15mm}(2)\\6x^2+2(x+1)^2-1=z^2\hspace {5mm}(3)\end{cases}$$
According to Wolfram, $(2)$ has no positive integer solution and $(3)$ has infinitely many (determine similarly to Pell-Fermat equation); however among these some particular $x$ must have the form $x=2^{k-1}n$ for $k$ odd greater than $5$.

Calculating the two smaller we have $(x,z)=(10,29),(348,985)$ and we can see that $348=2^2\cdot87$; if the exponent would have been not $2$ but greater than or equal to $5(=6-1)$, we would have had a value of $ n $ to rule out another odd value of k. We stop this comment here concluding that a part of the values of k are as follows:

►**all even greater than $2$**

►probaly very much of odd values greater than $5$ (if not all!)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you question is about values of $k$ and $n$ that makes $2^kn^2+2^kn+1$ never to be a perfect square, where $k,n \in N$

We know that if $z$ is a perfect square, then $z^2+1$ cannot be a perfect square, this is the definition you'll use to solve your problem

$2^kn^2+2^kn+1 = 2^k\cdot(n^2+n)+1 = 2^k\cdot{n}\cdot(n+1)+1$

Now say $k=2m$ and $n=p^2$

$2^{2m}\cdot{p^2}\cdot(p^2+1)+1$

$( 2^m\cdot{p} )^2\cdot(p^2+1)+1$

Now if $p^2+1$ is a perfect square, then that expression can never be a perfect square

So we have to find the value of $p$ and $m$ that makes $p^2+1$ perfect, but $p^2+1$ cannot be a perfect square as we've shown earlier, since it can't be a perfect square then our expression is likely a perfect square if $k=2m$, meaning if $k$ is even and if $n=p^2$, meaning if $n$ is perfect, otherwise our expression is cannot be a perfect square

$2^kn^2+2^kn+1$ cannot be a perfect square, if $k$ is odd and $n$ is a perfect square

Comment: But for example if we let $k = 4$ then I can't find numerically any perfect squares...can you provide me an example, when $k = 2m$ will ever give a perfect square?

Comment: Are you looking for when the expression is a perfect square or not, my work is based on if it cannot be and this happens when $k$ is odd and $n$ is a perfect square

Comment: But I am looking in general for any $n$. Which means a value for $k$ where there will no $n$ exists such that the equation will ever be a perfect square. I edited the question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

We know that any perfect square is either modulo $\ 0$ or $\ 1$ mod $\ 4$.
Let $\ 2^kn^2+2^kn+1$ be a perfect square.

Then either $\ 2^kn^2+2^kn+1 \equiv 0 (mod 4)$

But $\ 4\not|\;(2^kn^2+2^kn+1)=2^k(n^2+n)+1 $, because $\ 2^k(n^2+n)+1 $ is odd.

So $\ 2^k(n^2+n)+1 \not\equiv 0 (mod 4)$

Therefore $\ 2^k(n^2+n)+1 \equiv 1 (mod 4)$

$\implies 4|2^k(n^2+n)$

$\implies either\quad 4|2^k\; or\quad 4|n^2+n\implies 4|n(n+1)  $

$\implies k=2p\quad or\quad n=4q\;, 4q-1,\quad p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$
Contrapositively we can say that if $\ k\ne 2p\:$ and $\ n\neq 4q,(4q-1)$ then $\ 2^kn^2+2^kn+1$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: Your "either-or" statement is wrong, because $n$ and $n+1$ are consecutive numbers, so one of them must be even, meaning that $n(n+1)$ must always contribute at least one factor of $2$, but might contribute more (e.g. $16,17$). Thus you can only conclude that either $4\mid n(n+1)$ or $k>1$. These conditions assure that $4\mid 2^k(n^2+n)$

Comment: Since here the quotient is  $\ 4$ so divisibility by  $\ 2$ is not necessary to consider. Also divisibility by  $\ 4$ ensures divisibility by  $\ 2$ but not the converse. Thus we need such numbers that are divisible by both  $\ 2$ and $\ 4$ and hence by  $\ 4$. The only case where $\ 4|n(n+1)$ does not satisfy is for $\ n=1$. But $\ 4|2k(n^2+n)$ for  $\ n=1$ also.  $\ \mathbf{\text{ Although I am not satisfied with my proof, phew}}$. @KeithBackman

Answer (score -1):

If $\ 2^kn^2+2^kn+1$ is a perfect square, then $\ 2^kn^2+2^kn+1=0$ must have two equal roots, i.e the discriminant must vanish.
Therefore
$\ \begin{align} 
&(2^k)^2 =4.2^k.1\\
\implies &4^k =4.2^k\\
\implies &4^{k-1} =2^k\\
\implies &2^{2k-2} =2^k\\
\implies &2k-2 =k\\
\implies &k=2\\ 
\end{align}$
So $\ 2^kn^2+2^kn+1$ is a perfect square if $\ k=2\; \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus if $\ k\ne2$ then $\ 2^kn^2+2^kn+1$ is not a perfect square.